# Laravel - Add related email to returned array of ID's from different table

Tags: php, laravel-4, eloquent

I have a function which checks a belongsToMany relationship table and returns all results:

```
// $tasks variable
public function getTasks()
{
    return UserExternalAccount::whereIn( 'external_account_id', $this->roleUser->getRolesForUser() )
        ->get();
}
```

In this table there is two fields, user_id and external_account_id.

What I want to do, is when returning that object, also add into that the email address that related to the the user_id.

So I would like to be able to do:

```
$tasks->email;
```

How can I add that into the return from the getTasks() object?

Thanks.

Comment: Please show the relationships of the `UserExternalAccount`-model.

Comment: No relationship set up for that model, that table is the result of two belongToMany relationships.

Comment: Well, that's really hard to answer then... Your approach doesn't really look right. A pivot table should not have a model, and you should not have to query it directly. What you actually want to do is to fetch Tasks with the associated users, but also want to limit the results to external users only, so the syntax should look something like `$tasks = User::external()->tasks;`, right? You can achieve this e.g. with [scopes](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#query-scopes), and also have a look at [eager loading](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#eager-loading).

Comment: Do that :) And while you're at it, maybe also have a look at the [Mayn-to-many relationships section](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#many-to-many) to see some examples of how Laravel handles them. Feel free to come back and update your question if you're still having trouble.

Comment: Which table hold your email?

Comment: @VijaySankhat a 'users' table.

Comment: Then you may have to join with users table to get user's email